# subclass as specialization - ie: adding a method in the specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I want to add an additional conversion operator to a specialization of a template

-can a spelcialization inherit all methods from its main template ?

```
template<class T>
MyClass
{
public:
    operator Foo() { return(getAFoo()); }
};


template<>
MyClass<Bar>
{
public:
    // desire to ADD a method to a specialization yet inherit
    // all methods from the main template it specializes ???
    operator Bar() { return(getABar()); } 
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Template specializations are distinct types and thus don't share functions.

You can get shared functionality by inheriting from a common base class:

```
template<class T>
struct Base {
    operator Foo() { return Foo(); }
};

template<class T>
struct C : Base<T> {
    // ...
};

template<>
struct C<Bar> : Base<Bar> {
    // ...
    operator Bar() { return Bar(); }
};
```